# Perform given PHP task if no response from cURL request

Tags: php, curl

How can I perform a cURL request and perform a given action if there is no response from the remote machine?

The script is running in the background, and I am not concerned about making the user wait.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://example.com/bla.php');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('x'=>'cba!','y'=>'abc'));
if($result = curl_exec($ch)) {
    //do this
}
else {
    //do this if no response after 5 seconds
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)  and [CURLOPT_TIMEOUT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); //timeout in seconds
```

Comment: Thanks MrFreezer.  I will test it.  I assume my `if($result = curl_exec($ch))` will hang for 5 seconds and then result in false?

Comment: After testing, I will comment on my findings. Thanks!

Comment: Only other suggestion is to check for missing page HTTP 404.

Comment: `if($result = curl_exec($ch)) {$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 404) {`

Comment: I just did it really simple `if($response = curl_exec($ch) && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)==200) {...}`